# Python-remove highly similar string from dataset

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a genomic dataset contained base messages, like this:

> Position        samp1    samp2    samp2   samp3   samp4   samp5   samp6 ...
>   posA  T       T       T       T       T       T       T  ...
>   posB  G       A       A       G       G       A       A  ...
>   posC  G       G       G       G       G       G       G  ...
>   ...

This file has 100000+ lines, each line contains 200 bases of 200 samples.
Now i want to remove positons which haves high similar base in every samples, pic below is of 100 % the same, and i will remove one of them
[image: similar positions]

we defined similar ratio as (similar base number) / (sequence length):

> posH C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C
>   posI A       C       C       C       A       C       C       C

similarity of posH and posI is 6 / 8 = 75%
As required, similar ratio above 99% is regarded as highly similay, and remove one of the similar positions.

How can i do this work in python efficiently?
Thank you.

Comment: How is this dataset saved in run time? Is it a dataframe?

Comment: Does a given section of every single sample need to be similar to remove the sequence, or if 2+ samples have similar sections do you want to remove them?

Comment: the data is stored as dict, positions as key, the following sequence as value.

Comment: I want to remove positions which have similarity in 99% samples.

Answer (score 5):

Similarity of `6/8` between `posH` and `posI`, looks like you want inverse of normalized [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) (i.e. `1-d`).

You can compute inverse normalized hamming distance between two sequences using:

```
def inverse_hamming_distance(a,b):
    z = list(zip(a, b))
    return sum(e[0]==e[1] for e in z) / len(z)
```

and it gives:

```
>>> inverse_hamming_distance('CCCCCCCC', 'ACCCACCC')
0.75
```

However you can save some CPU cycle by *early* detecting that two lines are **not** similar. Given the minimum similarity threshold `t`, if you observe `int(0.5+(1-t)*len(z))` dissimilar items, you don't need to go til the end, and you can already tell items are not similar.

```
def similar(a,b,t=0.99):
    l = min(len(a), len(b))
    t = int(0.5 + l*(1 - t))
    n = 0
    for a1, b1 in zip(a, b):
        if a1 != b1:
            n += 1
        if n > t:
            return False
    return True
```

test:

```
>>> similar('CCCCCCCC', 'ACCCACCC', 0.75)
True
>>> similar('CCCCCCCC', 'ACCCACCC', 0.9)
False
```

Comment: Won't this require comparing a large number of items against each other? Is there something that can be done (early on) partitioning the items to avoid having to do so many comparisons?

Comment: kd-tree could help with that, but the implementation of that can be tricky

Answer (score 2):

First to speed this up a lot, start by storing all the data as lists of integers or binary before comparing. Either would dramatically reduce the memory required for the comparison operation. An enumerable would be a good fit. When you do this I would also split each dictionary value into a list with each item a specific sample: `basedict = { 'posA' : [samp1, samp2,...] , ... }`.

```
from enum import Enum
Base = Enum('Base', 'A C T G')
```

@mescalinum's answer has a good description on how to use a function to calculate whether two lines are similar:

```
def similar(a,b,t=0.99):
l = min(len(a), len(b))
t = int(0.5 + l*(1 - t))
n = 0
for a1, b1 in zip(a, b):
    if a1 != b1:
        n += 1
    if n > t:
        return False
return True
```

All that's left is to make a loop that works for your dataset. `similarpositions` gives a list of the keys to every position deemed 'similar.'

```
similarpositions = []
for key in basedict:
    samplecomps = (len(basedict[key]) * (len(basedict[key]) - 1)) / 2 # number of comparisons between samples needed
    dissimilar = 0
    for item1 in basedict[key]:
        for item2 in basedict[key]:
            if similar(item1, item2, 0.99) == False:
                dissimilar += 1
                if samplecomps / dissimilar > 0.01: // break once we know too many dissimilar results, to save unneeded comparisions
                    break
        if samplecomps / dissimilar > 0.01:
            break
    if samplecomps / dissimilar <= 0.01:
        similarpositions.append(key)
```

Comment: Here item1 and item2 are elements from [samp1, samp2,...].
I don't know why compare item1 and item2 by `similar(item1, item2, 0.99)` or item1 and item2 are long strings of bases?